# How to retrieve all project scheduled pipelines in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-omnibus

I need to do a backup & restore to upgrade Gitlab compute instance. In the restored Gitlab instance, I need to retrieve all scheduled pipelines and disable them from running automatically. However, we have hundreds of projects. That would take quite a while to look up by each project for CI / CD schedule. Is there an easy way to retrieve all project scheduled pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

This Gitlab documentation link answers my question: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/enable_or_disable_ci.html